# how to deduct the formula that gives the derivative of $f(x) = x^2$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Okay so the problem is: Define the derivative, and demonstrate how you can deduct the formula that gives the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$
, and the rule $(f+g)(x)' = f'(x) + g'(x)$.

I know the derivative is the slope of the tangent line to the graph, but I have no idea how to deduct the formula.

Comment: You say you know that the derivative is the slope of the tangent line to the graph. Can you put that into symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of derivative:
$$ f'(x)=\lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}   $$
Or
$$ f'(x)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}    $$

So for $f(x)=x^2$ we have:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=  \lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{(x+dx)^2-x^2}{dx}=\lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{x^2+2xdx+(dx)^2 -x^2}{dx}=\lim_{dx \to 0} 2x+dx=2x$$

Also for the other proof:

Let h(x) = f(x)+g(x)

Then:
$$h'(x)=\lim_{dx \to 0}\frac{h(x+dx) -h(x)}{dx}=\lim_{dx \to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)+g(x+dx) -f(x)-g(x)}{dx}  =  f'(x)=\lim_{dx \to 0} (\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx} + \frac{g(x+dx)-g(x)}{dx})=f'(x)+g'(x)      $$